# Merge Error: Not Enough Memory

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, merge, dissolve, standard-license-level

I'm attempting to make a flood plain map for a school project, and am using FEMA Flood Hazard Symbology for the legend. I've dissolved by a Flood Zone Field, but am left with two attributes both named "X" they are slightly different, but for what I need it does not matter.

I want to consolidate these attributes into one. So far I've tried to merge them using the editor toolbar. The process starts to run, but ArcMap locks up and eventually says the merge cannot be completed: Not enough memory. I'm running Arc on a computer with 8Gb or RAM. Is there another way to consolidate these into one, or a way to not make it lock up?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]Outside of an edit session - try using the DISSOLVE tool - under Data Management Tools > Generalization.  This should accomplish what you are trying to do I believe.  Leave the Create multi-part features option checked on.

Comment: Isn't that the same Dissolve Tool under the Geoprocessing options? I dissolved it to the point it is at now.

Comment: Yes, dissolve will merge these together though - as long as the attributes are exactly the same!

Comment: This gave me 4 "X" attributes :-(

Comment: This works for me - are you making sure the Create multi-part feature is checked on?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like there's a difference between 'X' and 'X'. I think you need to make them both the same: select all the features with 'X' and use the field calculator to populate them with 'X' - yes it sounds the same, but there's probably a leading or trailing space which will become evident when you select by attributes on 'FLD_ZONE', list the unique values and you get two 'X' values, you want to select both of them and field calculate to the same value and then they will dissolve properly.

BTW ArcGis is still a 32bit application and regardless of how much memory is installed will only use 4GiB of memory

Comment: Agreed - you  must ensure they are the same if you use the dissolve or any other geoprocessing tool that looks at attributes